# Heightmap implementation in javascript question, a 2D water heightmap

Tags: mathematics, heightmap

I have a **height map function** from [GPU Gems 2 Chapter 18](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/gpu-gems-2-chapter-18-using-vertex-texture-displacement-realistic-water-rendering), where they're generating a set of B/W pixels from this equation:

*H(x,y,t) = Σ<sub>i=0</sub><sup>N</sup> h ( 
A<sup>x</sup><sub>i</sub> x + B<sup>x</sup><sub>i</sub>,  
A<sup>y</sup><sub>i</sub> y + B<sup>y</sup><sub>i</sub>,  
A<sup>t</sup><sub>i</sub> x + B<sup>t</sup><sub>i</sub> )*

The article suggests using 4 height maps to generate the final height map, so that's N = 4. I understand it's using 3 equations of a line to describe the 2D plotting of a 1D B/W pixel. So, I have to iterate through a set of points, say from (0,0) to (100,100):

- [
  x<sub>0</sub> - x<sub>100</sub>**,** 
  y<sub>0</sub> - y<sub>100</sub>**,**, 
  t<sub>0</sub> - t<sub>100</sub>
  ]

So that's a "for loop" of 100 x 100 x 100 and with the 4 times that's 100 x 100 x 100 x 4 loops, the number of A's,B's and T's, i.e. the data I would need to provide would be:

- [ 
  A<sub>0</sub><sup>x</sup>**,**
  A<sub>0</sub><sup>y</sup>**,**
  A<sub>0</sub><sup>t</sup> 
  ] , [ 
  B<sub>0</sub><sup>x</sup>**,**
  B<sub>0</sub><sup>y</sup>**,**
  B<sub>0</sub><sup>t</sup> 
  ]
- [ 
  A<sub>1</sub><sup>x</sup>**,**
  A<sub>1</sub><sup>y</sup>**,**
  A<sub>1</sub><sup>t</sup> 
  ] , [ 
  B<sub>1</sub><sup>x</sup>**,**
  B<sub>1</sub><sup>y</sup>**,**
  B<sub>1</sub><sup>t</sup> 
  ]
- [ 
  A<sub>2</sub><sup>x</sup>**,**
  A<sub>2</sub><sup>y</sup>**,**
  A<sub>2</sub><sup>t</sup> 
  ] , [ 
  B<sub>2</sub><sup>x</sup>**,**
  B<sub>2</sub><sup>y</sup>**,**
  B<sub>2</sub><sup>t</sup> 
  ]
- [ 
  A<sub>3</sub><sup>x</sup>**,**
  A<sub>3</sub><sup>y</sup>**,**
  A<sub>3</sub><sup>t</sup> 
  ] , [ 
  B<sub>3</sub><sup>x</sup>**,**
  B<sub>3</sub><sup>y</sup>**,**
  B<sub>3</sub><sup>t</sup> 
  ]

My question is, is this correct? Are my for loops correct? Did I interpret the equation OK so that its just 4 for loops of 4x100x100x100 and the 24 pieces of data are all I need to generate this map?

I'm implementing this in javascript, using a plot pixel function.

Edit: I have another problem, how do I output the data? If I have say a 100x100 pixel height map, how do I "keep" only the data that applies to that area, do I just "throw away" the rest of the data in a conditional if statement that only does within that range?

Edit: also it was my understanding that x and y were the plots for the u and v of the height map and t was that alpha channel? I think I'm misunderstanding that part if the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the article seems correct, it is explaining a process of superimposing 4 separate height maps onto each other to represent surface displacement with water. You could write it as four separate loops if you wanted, but why not condense it into a single loop that accesses each of the four height maps each iteration?

Comment: I'd love to if I could understand how to do it. It's probably very simple, but all this math is confusing me a bit.

Comment: You should start by thinking about what you are trying to do, and understand the solution from a ten thousand foot view first. Height map displacement is a process by which a vertex is displaced vertically using a black and white color scale, black being the negative peak, and white being the positive. This article describes a process of blending heightmaps, as well as selecting the most appropriate map based on the distance the water is from the view point.

Comment: Also, they represent their height maps using three components, not simply two. The first two components (x/y) represent colorized displacement, while the third component represents time. The equation that they have simply demonstrates how they sum these components from separate height maps to generate a displacement at a specific location. Focus less on the specific details of the implementation, and more on understanding the theory behind the implementation. You may then find yourself writing a simpler (or better) solution based on the context.